# Error: Matcher not found: equals

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, clang-ast-matchers

I am trying to use clang ASTMatcher to find if statments that has a condition with RHS as integer value 0 or 0.0f. For this purpose, I was able to write a query as follows:

```
clang-query> match ifStmt(hasCondition(binaryOperator(hasRHS(integerLiteral(equals(0)))))
```

When I am using the above query I get the error as follows:

```
1:2: Error parsing argument 1 for matcher ifStmt.
1:9: Error parsing argument 1 for matcher hasCondition.
1:22: Error parsing argument 1 for matcher binaryOperator.
1:37: Error parsing argument 1 for matcher hasRHS.
1:44: Error parsing argument 1 for matcher integerLiteral.
1:59: Matcher not found: equals
```

But, when I refer the online guide at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html, it says that Matcher equals is available:

```
Matcher<IntegerLiteral> equals  const ValueT Value

Matches literals that are equal to the given value of type ValueT.

Given
  f('false, 3.14, 42);
characterLiteral(equals(0))
  matches 'cxxBoolLiteral(equals(false)) and cxxBoolLiteral(equals(0))
  match false
floatLiteral(equals(3.14)) and floatLiteral(equals(314e-2))
  match 3.14
integerLiteral(equals(42))
  matches 42

Note that you cannot directly match a negative numeric literal because the
minus sign is not part of the literal: It is a unary operator whose operand
is the positive numeric literal. Instead, you must use a unaryOperator()
matcher to match the minus sign:

unaryOperator(hasOperatorName("-"),
              hasUnaryOperand(integerLiteral(equals(13))))

Usable as: Matcher<CharacterLiteral>, Matcher<CXXBoolLiteralExpr>,
           Matcher<FloatingLiteral>, Matcher<IntegerLiteral>
```

I am using llvm-4.0 and clang 3.8 on Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am also exploring a bit on AST Matchers. I was also facing same problem with clang-query, however when I used the same matcher expression in a small cpp file (example can be found here https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html) and compiled it to an executable and passed the file in which if I want to check "if statements", it showed the results correctly.

For some reasons, equals() is not available in clang-query.